# solving expression in a buffer

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to create a function (in C) to solve an addition that is placed in a buffer variable. So far it works for equations that result in single-digit numbers, however if the result is more than one digit, it causes problems.. For example, if I place 2+3+5+2 in the buffer, outputs 102, not 12. Can anyone point out where my errors are and how I can fix them?

Here's my code:

```
char buffer[50];

void *adder(void)
{
    int bufferlen;
    int value1, value2;
    int startOffset, remainderOffset;
    int i;
    char result[10];
    while (1) 
    {
        startOffset = remainderOffset = -1;
        value1 = value2 = -1;

        bufferlen = strlen(buffer);
        for (i = 0; i < bufferlen; i++) {
            if(value1 == -1)
            {
                if(isNumeric(buffer[i]))
                {
                    value1 = string2int(&buffer[i]);
                    startOffset = i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(buffer[i] == 43)
                {
                    if(isNumeric(buffer[i+1]))
                    {
                        value2 = string2int(&buffer[i+1]);
                        remainderOffset = i+1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(value1 != -1 && value2 != -1)
            {
                int k=0;
                int j=0;
                int2string((value1 + value2),result);
                /* print out the number we've found */
                fprintf(stdout, "Re:%s\n", result);
                int resultlen = strlen(result);
                for(k=startOffset; k < bufferlen; k++)
                {
                    if(j < resultlen)
                    {
                        buffer[k] = result[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* shift the remainder of the string to the left */
                        printf("A1-Buffer:%s\nk=%i\n", buffer, k);
                        if(j > 0)
                        buffer[k] = buffer[k+2];
                        else
                        buffer[k] = buffer[k+2];
                        printf("A2-Buffer:%s\n", buffer);
                        i = i - remainderOffset;
                        startOffset = remainderOffset = -1;
                        value1 = value2 = -1;   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    break;
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Ah, sorry, forgot about the extra functions. This function is for a school assignment and the isNumeric() and String2int() are exactly the same as isdigit() and atoi() and were given to us to use in the function.

**Edit 2:** After the numbers are added, the result has to be added back into the buffer in the expressions place like so: (2+3) -> (5) the reason is that eventually more functions will be written to handle multiplication, division, etc. This is where my main frustration lies - putting the result in place of the expression and shifting the buffer left the proper amount.

Comment: use:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag because this isn't C++ at all, and the "function" tag because it was meaningless. This is incredibly complicated for what it is supposed to do, and likely there are problems in the custom functions you aren't showing us…

Comment: What is significant about the number `43`?  The code would be more readable if you used `if (buffer[i] == '+')`.

Comment: Okay, I give up. What's the purpose of the `while` loop and how do you break out of it?

Comment: Would it be better to compute the result as you go, and when you've finished with the string, format the result back.  Also, wouldn't it be better to pass the input string as an argument to the function?

Comment: Troubadour: Everything up to the for loop was given in the assignment. I had a break to get out of the loop, looks like it didn't make the copy and paste. I'll put it back in. Not sure why the while loop, doesn't seem to do anything. Just kept it there because it was given.

Comment: @John: I suspect the `while` loop is supposed to do what you are doing with your `i` `for` loop. I would stick with the `while` as your `i` loop doesn't look right (see my answer for more details). Just break out of the `while` loop when there are no more additions to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char buffer[50];
```

Why 50 bytes? Why not 100? You should accept a pointer as an argument instead of relying on a global. Also, `buffer` is not a descriptive name.

```
void *adder(void)
```

The function does not return a `void *`; it has no return value. You might consider

```
/* return value of expression */
int evaluate_add_expression( char const *in_string )
```

or

```
/* return status code */
int evaluate_add_expression( char const *in_string, int *out_value )
```

Next, you declare a number of variables without initializing them. Move the declarations into the loop and include initializations with the declarations, i.e. `int value1 = -1, value2 = -1;` Of course, those names are also not descriptive at all.

```
            if(buffer[i] == 43)
```

The value `'+'` is a better way to represent the plus character than the magic number 43.

---

If I were you, I'd avail myself of the `sscanf` function.

```
int evaluate_add_expression( char const *in_string, int *sum ) {
    int addend;
    size_t offset, offset_delta;

    if ( sscanf( in_string, " %d %zn", sum, &offset ) != 1 ) return 1;

    while ( sscanf( in_string + offset, "+ %d %zn", &addend, &offset_delta ) == 1 ) {
        * sum += addend;
        offset += offset_delta;
    }

    return in_string[ offset ] != '\0'; /* check that all input was consumed */
}
```

This works fine and is about 15% as long.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, **everything** up to the first for loop was given. I am supposed to expand off of it. I will research sscanf, that might be a big help. Would there be a way with sscanf to know where the numbers are in the string?.. see my above edit.

Comment: @John: You should be more clear that this is homework. Asking me to do your homework is unrealistic. In the real world, when things are "given" as such then the problem is with the company/organization. My answer is the solution to the given problem. `sscanf` knows where the numbers are in the string because the space characters in the format string direct it to ignore whitespace.

Comment: Im not trying to make you do my homework, my inital asking was just for where I was going wrong. I plan on doing my homework myself, I think I just didn't ask my question properly - my main concern was with multiple-digit numbers overwriting the remainder of the buffer when I put them back. Then everyone found other errors in my code.

Comment: @John: I'm sorry I can't be more helpful, but things go wrong at line 1 as far as I can tell. The fact that I don't know what pointer the function is supposed to return, or how it is supposed to modify the buffer, mean that this can't be answered completely. There *are* several major problems, such as shifting the entire buffer to the left (an inefficient way of parsing), and `atoi` failing to tell you how many digits were read (which `%zn` does for me). It looks like some fundamental tools are missing.

Comment: Thats alright, thank you for the help you have given! Yes it is poorly written, I am still learning and it seems the assignment wasn't written too well to begin with, but I will try to put your suggestions into practice and see if they help me any.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
 if(j > 0)
     buffer[k] = buffer[k+2];
 else
     buffer[k] = buffer[k+2];
```

executes the same code regardless of the value of `j`. Also note that `j` can never be negative in your code anyway.

You are going out of bounds on your buffer array. Your loop counter `i` is being incremented by one at the end of each loop but you are also doing

```
i = i - remainderOffset;
```

*multiple times* in the `k` loop. Surely that must give you a negative `i`?

Also, when you shift the buffer back with

```
 buffer[k] = buffer[k+2];
```

the loop takes `k` up to `bufferLen` so `k+2` is out of bounds here too.

I'm not sure why you shift everything back by a fixed amount of two positions anyway? Surely that assumes you just added a single digit number?

Think about these issues and you'll start to see where you are going wrong. I would agree with others that if you can leverage existing code then do so.

**Edit: In response to your comment**

I assume it's part of the assignment to store the result in the buffer? If not then just keep track of it in an integer and everything simplifies enormously. If the assignment says you have to update the buffer with intermediate results then note the following:

Suppose the two numbers at the start of the current buffer position are called A and B and that A is a two digit number and B a three digit number. There are two possible outcomes in terms of the amount of storage you need for the result, R. Either it is

```
AA+BBB+remainder -> RRR+remainder
```

or

```
AA+BBB+remainder -> RRRR+remainder
```

This means that you have a variable shift depending on how many digits the result has so, yes, you could base it on `resultLen` (but it isn't `resultLen` itself). Note that if you shift back you need to fill the gaps you leave at the end of the buffer with some suitable character or keep track of where the real end of the buffer now is.

Rather than shift the remainder backwards I would keep it where it is and write the result in the correct place before it (unless your assignment explicitly asks you to shift it backwards of course). So you take

```
AA+BBB
```

and convert it to either

```
...DDD
```

or

```
..DDDD
```

where the dots represent the characters we are no longer interested in. The characters there won't matter as long as you've updated the starting index on each iteration of the `while` loop (get rid of the `i` loop). If you know the number of digits that A, B and R have this shouldn't be too difficult for you to work out. Finally, break out of the `while` loop when the starting index hits `bufferLen`.

Comment: The reason I did the i = i- remainderOffset is so that if you have, for example (2+3)*8 in the buffer, the remainderOffset would be the index of the "3" in the buffer. I was trying to move i back to the beginning of the expression so that the expression can be replaced with the result. `In buffer: (2+3)*8 -> add 2+3 -> replace expression with in buffer result -> (5)*8`. To shift the buffer left, could I do something such as `buffer[k] = buffer[k + strlen(result)]` if the result of the addition was placed in a char result variable?